# Javascript - Send keycode on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a keydown event starts with:

```
   $(document).keydown(function(evt) {
            switch(evt.keyCode)
            {
               case ...:
```

I want to trigger it with keycode 37 on page load. First page load is not important. It may send it on every refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.trigger()` and pass an object with the keyCode predefined:

```
$(document).trigger({ 
    type: 'keydown',
    keyCode: 37
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/UvBw9/

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which will be bound to the `case 37` and simply call it on `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //this is self-invoking function. It is called immediately after being created
    (function key37Handler() {
        //...
    })();

    $(document).keydown(function(evt) {
        switch(evt.keyCode)
        {
            case 37:
                key37Handler();
                break;
            case ...:
            //...
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function eventRaiser(){
  var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
  e.which = 37; // # Some key code value
  $("input").trigger(e);
}
Window.onbeforeunload = eventRaiser;
```